# Fan won't turn off on shutdown

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I am trying to make sure my fan turns off when I power off my raspberry pi (without having to unplug it). My fan is connected to the 3.3V pin. I didn't connect it to the 5V pin because I deemed the 3.3V was good enough and the noise was less.

I used the following commands in attempt to make sure my fan was off when I powered down my pi:

```
MAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1
```

Then I shutdown my pi:
`sudo shutdown -h now`

Fan is still running though and I have to unplug it from the power adapter to fully turn it off.

Also, does anyone know how I can power my pi back up after shutting it down without need a power button. I am assuming definitely not, but worth a shot to ask!

BTW, I am running ubuntu.

Comment: what action or signal are you seeking to power the pi on again?  External circuitry can simulate a "power button" for whatever action you are considering.

Comment: The 3V3 supply is disabled upon `halt`, `shutdown`, or `poweroff` commands if you have `WAKE_ON_GPIO=0` ***AND*** `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1`. To re-boot, you can **momentarily** short `GLOBAL_EN` to ground. More details in [this old-ish answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114422/what-is-the-minimum-power-required-for-an-rpi-4-in-halt-or-shutdown/114423#114423), and [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114440/starting-pi-4-with-global-en/114446#114446). I don't use a button, but I do have a wire jammed in `GLOBAL_EN` via that I "scratch" on a USB housing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md

```
MAKE_ON_GPIO=1
```

Should be:

```
WAKE_ON_GPIO=0
^ W not M    ^ 0 not 1
```

and you must also set:

```
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1
```

Both of these parameters must be set to disable the 3V3 supply on `halt`, `shutdown` or `poweroff`.

Also, you did not say how you "used the following commands" but if you just entered them as environment variables or something that won't work; you need to edit the bootloader config in the EEPROM.  There are instructions on the page linked above.

Comment: Just tried myself on a Pi4B.  You do need to have `WAKE_ON_GPIO=0` and `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1`  for the 3V3 pins to be switched off.

Answer (score 3):

While I think powering a fan from 3.3V is a bad idea (it is easy enough to power from 5V and use a transistor to control it) the settings you are using are mutually incompatible.

You can not have power off and WAKE_ON_GPIO=1

POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1 turns off the PMIC and removes all power except 5V

Comment: You must set both `WAKE_ON_GPIO=0` and `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1` to disable the 3V3 output after `halt`, `shutdown` or `poweroff`.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? I actually run a 5V fan from 3.3V to make it quieter.

Comment: Some fans don't run as well or can break when run for long periods at voltages higher or lower than their rating. In practice, I haven't seen an issue with most of the fans I've run this way, but they do likely cool less efficiently, and you probably void the warranty.