# Is it possible to reboot my pi3b+ after I have run sudo halt without unplugging it and replugging it back in?

Tags: pi-3b+

Is it possible to reboot my pi3b+ after I have run sudo halt without unplugging it and replugging it back in?    I do not like pulling the power out of the micro usb over and over as I do not want to damage it and have turned it off already because I thought it was no longer needed.

My setup is just a rpi3b+ with sense hat if that has any dependency to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can reboot with a button connected to pin 5.

See raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19754/8697

You can also reboot most models by pulling the RUN pin LOW.

The latest models with PMIC chips (basically Pi3 on) can be rebooted by pulling GLOBAL_EN low.
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100234/8697

Comment: Other idea is just to pull the mains adapter out of the wall (or flick the switch if the socket has one fitted)!

Answer (score 1):

You can buy these USB power switches for Rpi 1 to 3 and a USB-C type for Rpi4. I have one on each of my Pis. Around 3 to 5 UK pounds or equivalent. They often have an LED to show when power is on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to fiddle the USB plug out of the Pi each time you want to reboot it or switch it off, you can also unplug the power adapter. This is far less likely to cause any damage. Alternatively, buy an extension cord with a switch to power the Pi. I use one that shuts off all my lab equipment from mains at once.