# How to boot and safely shutdown with a button when WAKE_ON_GPIO=0

Tags: boot, pi-4, power, hat, shutdown

### 1. Description

To boot and shutdown my pi I have been using a button shorting `GPIO 3` an `GND`. However after shutting down the pi, the [fan shim](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-fan-shim) and HDD keep on running. To solve this I've edited the bootloader configuration to contain `WAKE_ON_GPIO=0` and `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1`. This of course caused my pi to stop booting when pressing the button. A possible solution to boot the pi is to short `GLOBAL_EN` and `GND` but it's not possible to safely shutdown this way.

What I would like to have, is a (simple) solution **safely** shutting down and booting the pi by pressing only **one** button. And while the pi is shutdown not to output any power to the usb ports, GPIO pins and Ethernet port. Does anyone know one?

Some clarification:
The thing I'm trying to solve is being able to boot the pi when in low power mode without pulling the plug.
With a simple solution I mean the simplest solution possible. I was hoping there to be a setting I could use. In the case there not being one, I was hoping there to be a HAT that could detect the pi being powered on, bringing a GPIO pin down to shut it down when it's on and bringing global_en down when it's not

### 2. Lessons learned while researching

#### 2.1. Booting the rpi

- The pi can be booted by bringing the `GPIO 3` pin down ([Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md))

#### 2.2. Shutdown

- The rpi can be safely shutdown by writing a py script and triggering it when a GPIO pin is brought down
- **Downside**: When shut down the usb devices, ethernet port and hat is still powered

#### 2.3. Powering down USB devices,...

- On shutdown the usb devices can be powered down by editing the bootloader config. ([Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md))
- **Downside**: the rpi cannot be booted anymore by bringing the `GPIO 3` pin down

#### 2.4. Alternative way of booting the rpi

- Bringin `GLOBAL_EN` down will reset the PMIC and will cause it to power up all its  outputs. This will boot the rpi. [source (Need to find an official one. But I've tested it)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117019/134318). Also mentioned in the [Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md)
- **Downside**: Bringing `GLOBAL_EN` down while the rpi is turned on will (not safely) reboot the pi.

#### 2.5. Extra

- The rpi still outputs 5v when shutdown, `WAKE_ON_GPIO=0` and `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi 3 model B "dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77905/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-dtoverlay-gpio-shutdown)

Comment: I've added a link in your question that shows what a ["fan shim"](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-fan-shim) is. In the future, it would be helpful to make your question as clear as possible when referring to such things. I've got a different take on your question now & will revise my answer if you'll acknowledge you're still interested in an answer. While you're pondering that, you might also edit your question to indicate if **power consumption** is of any consequence to you.

Comment: After 2.5 years, I'll assume the OP has ***lost interest***  :)

Answer (score 2):

#### RPi 4B 5V Power Bus

AFAIK, there is no command, `dtoverlay`, or bootloader configuration that will power off the 5V output on the RPi 4. Using `WAKE_ON_GPIO=0` and `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1` in the bootloader configuration will place the RPi 4 in a [***low power mode***](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114422/what-is-the-minimum-power-required-for-an-rpi-4-in-halt-or-shutdown/114423) upon `halt` `shutdown` or `poweroff`. In this *low power mode* the RPi's power consumption is reduced to approximately 40mA (200mW), but the 5V bus remains powered.

This seems to be the minimum power consumption when power is connected to the USB-C connector. As the RPi hardware and firmware are currently configured, achieving a lower power consumption requires "pulling the plug" - i.e. removing the input power.

#### Turning the fan OFF:

If your fan is connected to one of the 5V pins on the GPIO header, it will continue to draw current through the RPi - even if the RPi is put in [*"low power mode"*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114423/83790). But you have 3 options to remove power from your fan in *low power mode*:

1. Connect your fan directly to the 3V3 bus (e.g. direct to pin 1 or pin 17 on the GPIO header),
2. Use the `gpio-fan` overlay (e.g. `dtoverlay=gpio-fan,temp=42000,gpiopin=17`) with an external switch (NPN transistor). See `/boot/overlays/README` for details`.
3. Use any GPIO output pin (properly configured) with an external switch (NPN transistor) under control of your software.

The common salient point for all three options is that the 3V3 bus is shut down when the RPi 4 goes into  *low power mode*.

#### Re: Single Button to Toggle RPi ON & OFF

You asked for a "simple" solution, and by that I assume you mean a solution that does not involve any external hardware. I am not aware of any way to accomplish this that doesn't involve additional hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Maybe I should have been more clear. I'm using a fan shim, it's being controlled by GPIO 18 which is low in low power mode.
The thing I'm trying to solve is being able to boot the pi when in low power mode without pulling the plug. 
With a simple solution I mean the simplest solution possible. I was hoping there was a setting I could use. Now in this case I was hoping there to be a HAT that could detect the pi being powered on, bringing a GPIO pin down to shut it down when it's on and bringing global_en down when it's not .

Comment: @PieterHuybrechts: *fan shim*... No one seems to define that term. I'll guess it's a fan that with an interface that allows you to drive it with a 3V3 GPIO? Why do you think that makes a difference? Your comment seems very much at variance with your question! If all you want to do is boot from *low power mode* without pulling the plug, you can easily do that with a momentary pushbutton wired between the `GLOBAL_EN` via and GND. Could you try to clarify this please?

Comment: I've given my question another thought and there seems to be to much unnecessary information in it. The basic question is: how to boot and safely shutdown a rpi when:
- WAKE_ON_GPIO=0 and POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1
- Preferably using only one button (Maybe there is a hat which knows when to pull down a GPIO pin or GLOBAL_EN).

Comment: @PieterHuybrechts: For me, your question remains ambiguous. I would tend to agree with your opinion: *"there seems to be to much unnecessary information in it"*. For example, this part of your question: `The thing I'm trying to solve is being able to boot the pi when in low power mode without pulling the plug.` **That's easy: run `sudo halt` from `bash`, and connect a pushbutton between `GLOBAL_EN` and GND.** But you seem to want to be able to shut down by pushing this button also. I'll say it again: This requires external hardware. So you need to decide what it is you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have used gpio-shutdown to implement a shutdown button. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/77918/8697

The ONLY was to reboot if you have POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1 is to cycle power or pull the **GLOBAL_EN** pin LOW.

The **GLOBAL_EN** pin is connected to the MxL7704 power management chip, and pulling this low should be similar to cycling power. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100234/8697

Comment: You reminded me once that it was the `low-to-high` transition on `GLOBAL_EN` that caused the RPi to re-start from the "low power" mode (i.e. bootloader config contains `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1 ` and `WAKE_ON_GPIO=0` followed by `halt` or `shutdown`). AFAIK, that's still true. From this "low power mode", pulling `GLOBAL_EN` low - and keeping it low - reduces power consumption a wee bit more, but will never cause the RPi to restart. Releasing `GLOBAL_EN` to the control of its internal pullup results in the `low-to-high` transition that leads to the re-start.

Answer (score 0):

What about powering down the USB/Ethernet-chip when shutting down the Pi? I have not tested it, but found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530711/22552693 where it says it can be powered down at least on Pi3s and earlier.
There is some more to read about this here https://core-electronics.com.au/guides/disable-features-raspberry-pi/#USB

It could be done by a script that initiates with a regular shutdown. Something like this https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=331117#p2021981